# GWT:How to figure out HTMLPanel rendering is complete

Tags: javascript, html, gwt

I am working on an application which fetches HTML content from the server and displays it to the user. The content fetched from the server is a complete HTML document. I have used UiBinder to specify UI for the view.

```
<g:HTMLPanel ui:field="mainPanel" styleName="ap-mainPanel">
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

In the view I have setViewerContent(String content) method and also a member panel for holding content[contentPanel]

```
public void setViewerContent(String content)
{
    contentPanel = new HTMLPanel(content);
    contentPanel.setStyleName("ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    contentPanel.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            if(event.isAttached())
            {
                System.out.println("<-- rendering complete -->");
                isRenderComplete = true;                    
            }

        }
    });
    mainPanel.clear();
    mainPanel.add(contentPanel);
    addScrollHandler();
}
```

I add a scroll handler to the contentPanel which listens to the ScrollEvent and onScroll() calls the appropriate methods to fetch content from the server
based on whether scroll is at the top or bottom.

```
public void addScrollHandler() {
    Event.sinkEvents(contentPanel.getElement(), Event.ONSCROLL);
    contentPanel.addHandler(this, ScrollEvent.getType());
}

public void onScroll( ScrollEvent event )
{
    if( HelperUtils.isScrollAtBottom( event.getSource() ) )
    {
        if(isRenderComplete)
        {
          System.out.println("<-- Process Down scroll START-->");
          isRenderComplete = false;
          getUiHandlers().reachedMaxVerticalScrollPostion();

          System.out.println("<-- Process Down scroll END-->");
        }
    }

    if( HelperUtils.isScrollAtTop( event.getSource() ) )
    {
        if(isRenderComplete)
        {  
          System.out.println("<-- Process Up scroll START-->");
          isRenderComplete = false;                
          getUiHandlers().reachedMinVerticalScrollPostion();
          System.out.println("<-- Process Up scroll END -->");
        }

    }
}
```

The problem I was facing was as we render the content I see calls made to the server to fetch content continuously. New scroll events are being fired while the content fetched from the server is being rendered. We would not want this i.e while the content is being rendered we do not want the ScrollEvent to be fired. I tried the above code where I have attached AttachEvent.Handler() to contentPanel. A flag isRenderComplete is maintained which is turned true on contentPanel attach. This flag is used in the onScroll method before triggering any server call.This approach seems to work.

But I am not sure if this is the correct one. Does anyone has any better solution[s] ?

Also since we are creating new contentPanel everytime each fetch takes the scrollbar to the top. I tried to add a new HTMLPanel markerPanel with couple of line breaks to the contentPanel. Then in the onAttachOrDetach() of contentPanel tried to scroll to the markerPanel. This did not work.

```
public void setViewerContent(String content)
{
    contentPanel = new HTMLPanel(content);
    markerPanel = new HTMLPanel(" <br> <br> ");
    contentPanel.setStyleName("ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    contentPanel.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            System.out.println("<-- rendering complete -->");
            if(event.isAttached())
            {
                markerPanel.getElement().scrollIntoView();
                isRenderComplete = true;                    
            }

        }
    });
    mainPanel.clear();
    contentPanel.add(markerPanel);
    mainPanel.add(contentPanel);
    addScrollHandler();
}
```

Any suggestions ? we want the scroll to be at the bottom when we fetch new content and the scroll event should not be fired till the content fetched is rendered completely.

Answer (score 0):

Add the scroll handler after content is rendered and remove it when the panel is detached

```
public void setViewerContent(String content)
{
    contentPanel = new HTMLPanel(content);
    markerPanel = new HTMLPanel(" <br> <br> ");
    contentPanel.setStyleName("ap-mainPanel ap-scrollPanel"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    contentPanel.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {

        @Override
        public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
            System.out.println("<-- rendering complete -->");
            if(event.isAttached())
            {
                markerPanel.getElement().scrollIntoView();
                isRenderComplete = true;    
                addScrollHandler();
            }
            else
            {
                isRenderComplete = false;   
                removeScrollHandler();
            }

        }
    });
    mainPanel.clear();
    contentPanel.add(markerPanel);
    mainPanel.add(contentPanel);
}
```